# Worldpay PayPal Error : BAD_REQUEST, Required URL not specified and no default defined

Tags: paypal, payment, worldpay

WorldPay Paypal API respond with 400 error
I am following the code provided in [here](https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/make-paypal-payment) 
same code functionality is working for card payments 
attaching reference screenshot from postman
[image: Post URL and body part]

[image: Header Content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's Paypal payment, you need to specify return urls for handing the payment,... such as successUrl, pendingUrl,...
like the following:
You can find more details here:
https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/api#orders

```
{ 
    "token" : "YOUR-TOKEN", 
    "orderType" : "ECOM",
    "amount" : 500,
    "currencyCode" : "GBP",
    "orderDescription" : "Order description",
    "customerOrderCode":"Order code",
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "billingAddress" : {
        "address1" : "address1",
        "postalCode" : "postCode",
        "city" : "city",
        "countryCode" : "GB"
    },
    "deliveryAddress": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "address1": "address1",
        "postalCode": "postCode",
        "city": "city",
        "countryCode": "GB",
        "telephoneNumber": "02079460761"
    },
    "successUrl": "https://www.yourwebsite.co.uk/success",
    "pendingUrl": "https://www.yourwebsite.co.uk/pending",
    "failureUrl": "https://www.yourwebsite.co.uk/failure",
    "cancelUrl": "https://www.yourwebsite.co.uk/cancel",
    "shopperEmailAddress": "name@domain.co.uk",

}
```